# Why does the tor daemon start automatically in Ubuntu/Debian?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, startup

I'd like to know *why* the tor daemon autostarts and whether it's safe to disable it from starting automatically.

Here users asked how to disable it for [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256911/how-to-prevent-tor-from-starting-automatically-on-ubuntu-server) and [Debian](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12588/debian-tor-user-running-tor-in-the-background-from-startup).

Answer (score 1):

Normally users would expect network services that are installed to start automatically, this is true for other network services under debian or ubuntu like httpd or sshd.

If you're running a relay or an onion service or another service that depending on using tor as a client then you'd definitely want the tor system service to start automatically.